# How to represent foreign key lookup table in Django unit test?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models

I'm building three Django models that will allow users to create lists of items that represent activities (e.g. movies, concerts, and sporting events) they want to attend. Since each user can include one or more items (i.e. activities) in a list and multiple users may have the same item (activity) in one of their lists, there's a many-to-many relationship between lists and items:

The 'list_type' table is a foreign key lookup table that identifies what types of activity items (movies, etc.) are stored in a list.  I pre-populate this table via a Django migration when I run my initial migrations that create my tables.

```
# list/models.py
class ListType(models.Model):
    LIST_TYPES = (
        (1, 'Movie'),
        (2, 'Concert'),
        (3, 'Sport'),
    )
    type = models.CharField(_('type'), max_length=16)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'list_type'

class List(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    type = models.ForeignKey(ListType, help_text=_('Type of list'))
    name = models.CharField(_('list'), max_length=128, help_text=_('Name of list'))
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'list'
        unique_together = (('user', 'type', 'name'), )

class Item(models.Model):
      # value contains the pk of a movie, concert, or sporting event record
    lists = models.ManyToManyField(List, related_name='items').
    value = models.IntegerField(_('item'), help_text=_('Item in list'))
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'item'
```

I've been trying to represent the Type table with a factory-boy factory:

```
import factory
from list.models import ListType

class ListTypeFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    type = 'Movie'
    #type = ListType.objects.get(type='Movie')

    class Meta:
        model = Type
```

The problem I'm having is that when I run a unit test and am just setting things up, I get an error:

```
class ListTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.activity_type = ListTypeFactory(type='Member')

# => IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint...
# => "Key (type)=(Movie) already exists"
...
```

This makes sense as the Django TestCase test harness makes a copy of all my tables and the list_type table is prepopulated.  But what's the correct way to represent this table in a unit test?  Factory-boy doesn't appear to be the right mechanism and I don't want to touch the database to create an instance of the table as touching the database is a unit testing anti-pattern.